# Can I position an inner element below its parent?

Tags: css

It seems that with markup like **http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/**

```
<div id="container">
    Outer Div
    <div id="inner">Inner Div</div>
</div>
```

and CSS like

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

`#inner` is still above `#container` can I have `#inner` below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put it outside of inner element when it comes to HTML.
Here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/23/

```
<div id="container">
    Outer Div
</div>
<div id="inner">Inner Div</div>
```

Comment: This works, but you've lost the "grouping of the elements". How would you go about adding a style [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/25/)? *(based off my answer)*

Comment: I don't get the question. What style do you need to add? And into which revision?

Comment: Firstly: I'm not the person who asked the question. Secondly, that was just an example of something you *can't do* with your answer. When I say you've `lost the "grouping of the elements"`, I mean you can't, (for example!) add `width: 50%` to the container div and expect the inner div to behave as you'd expect. [`width: 50%` your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/27/) vs [`width: 50%` my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/28/).

Comment: This is not the answer to the question

Answer (score 4):

No.

The CSS 2.1 spec states this standard of painting elements:

1. the background and borders of the
   element forming the stacking
   context.
2. the child stacking contexts with
   negative stack levels (most negative
   first).
3. the in-flow, non-inline-level,
   non-positioned descendants.
4. the floating descendants.
5. the in-flow, inline-level,
   non-positioned descendants,
   including inline tables and inline
   blocks.
6. the child stacking contexts with
   stack level 0, and the positioned
   descendants with 'z-index: auto'.
7. the child stacking contexts with
   positive stack levels (least
   positive first).

Given these rules and your HTML, `#container` is creating the stacking context for the element `#inner`, which means `#container` has to be rendered first.

Other people have already posted alternative HTML/CSS to get the effect you desired, but if you want to know more about why what you want isn't possible, here is the documentation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    background: yellow;   
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index: 6;
}
#inner {
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 180px;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I guess i don't understand below. Doesn't just increasing the position to the top put it below?

Comment: I think he means below as in `z-index` style "underneath", not below as in "vertically lower down".

Comment: @thirthdot - oh, you mean under, or wait, below, damnit!

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to add an extra wrapper element, and to move `#inner` outside `#container`.

The extra wrapper element is given `position: relative`, so everything else should be the same as it was before, with the exception that `#inner` is underneath `#container`.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/nwekR/24/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible(in it's current state of having inner a child of container) because when the browser renders the DOM, it goes from top down on the DOM tree, and there is no way to draw under something that has already been drawn(i.e. drawing the parent before child).

You can read more about the z-index [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index).

There are ways of accomplishing(by changing the html around) this however, you can see thirtydot's solution.

Comment: You're right if you mean that "it's not possible *[without making changes to the HTML]*". Otherwise, see my answer.

Comment: No, he's rigorously right : the question is "render an element below its container". And that's impossible. You're (as you stated) are forced to change the relationship between the elements to put #inner below #container.

Comment: "it goes from top down on the DOM tree" is by against not exact : dom elements are not just drawn from top to bottom : siblings are drawn in the order of their z-index (and in top-to-bottom order if z-index are equal). (But it only applies to *siblings* - so that doesn't change anything related to the question).